# ffmpeg: option `unity` or `silence` not found for `afade`

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use `unity` and `silence` parameters of `afade` filter as documented [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade-1). To achieve partial fade-out, but getting an option not found error.

I am using ffmpeg version 5.1.2.

To reproduce:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "sine=frequency=500:duration=5" -filter_complex "afade=start_time=1:type=out:unity=0.1" -y test.wav
```

Error:

```
[Parsed_afade_0 @ 0x148004c30] Option 'unity' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x148004ba0] Error initializing filter 'afade' with args 'start_time=1:type=out:unity=0.1'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are currently available in git master builds, and will be available in ffmpeg 5.2 onwards.